# AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having a scenario where the `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` property of my `Configuration` class is not working in Entity Framework 6.

I set both the required properties to true, but yet I receive an update exception which states that potential data loss could occur. Ironically, it advices me to set the properties to true that I have already set to true.

Here's how I instantiate my model container (context).

```
Database.SetInitializer(new ModelInitializer());
Entities = new ModelContainer();
```

Here's the relevant part of my `ModelInitializer` class.

```
internal class ModelInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ModelContainer>
{

    private static bool _usedBefore;

    public void InitializeDatabase(ModelContainer context)
    {

        ...

        var migrateInitializer = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ModelContainer, Configuration>();
        migrateInitializer.InitializeDatabase(context);
    }
}
```

And finally, here's my `Configuration` class.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ModelContainer>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ModelContainer context)
    {

    }
}
```

My `ModelContainer` class (the context) basically just has a few properties and classes in it, so I don't think that's relevant to the problem. Here's the declaration though.

```
internal class ModelContainer : DbContext
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using the '-Force' parameter in the package manager console?

E.g.

```
Update-Database -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: The thing is that I am trying to do this programmatically. I don't have access to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using separate library for data access??

if yes then you need to provide its name when running query:

Add-Migration -StartUpProjectName "Your DAL Project" MyNewMigration

Update-Database -StartUpProjectName "Your DAL Project" -Verbose

Comment: I don't have access to the console as described in the other comments.